# Using Access VBA (DMax) function to use a table field and a variable in the Where/criteria column

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

This might be a basic formatting question, but for some reason I can't figure out a way get around it. The scenario that I have is that I want to use VBA to find the highest number from one field in a table in a given category (identified in another field in the same table). I have about eight categories, each with different numbers (e.g.)

```
ATD 500
ATD 250
ATD 700
MLK 500
MLK 120
PTO 900
```

I believe that the best way to do this would be to the DMAX Function, but for some reason I'm running into syntax errors no matter how I try to write it.

The code I'm work with so far is:

```
Dim HighestNumber As Variant
Dim HighCategory As Integer

HighCategory = InputBox("Please enter data", "ENTER", "ENTER")

HighestNumber = DMAX("[SaleValue]", "SalesTable", "[SalesCategory] = '" & HighCategory & "'")
```

---

(To clarify, [SaleValue] and [SalesCategory] are two columns in the access table "SalesTable", and I'm trying to set it up so that the user can enter a SalesCategory and get the highest SaleValue for that category. I'd like to be able to store that value somewhere for later use as well.)

Whenever I run this, I hit a Run-Time error '5', invalid procedure call on the last line. I'm fairly sure that it's a syntax error but I can't make heads or tales of why. I tried reading this site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/application-dmax-method-access

But they focus on hardcoded criteria and I can't find a good example of how to use DMax where the criteria should be designated by the user.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

EDIT: Changing the code as follows produces the same error

```
Dim HighestNumber As Long
Dim HighCategory As String

HighCategory = InputBox("Please enter data", "ENTER", "ENTER")

HighestNumber = DMAX("[SaleValue]", "SalesTable", "[SalesCategory] = '" & HighCategory & "'")
```

Comment: Seems valid, but you're missing a closing brace at the end of your `DMAX` (`HighestNumber = DMAX("[SaleValue]", "SalesTable", "[SalesCategory] = '" & HighCategory & "'")`. Sure that isn't it?

Comment: Erik von Asmuth -- Thank you for your reply! That's actually a copy paste error on my end -- there should be a parenthesis there and there is one in my actual code. I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified that the HighCategory is an Integer, however this should either be a string or a variant, as isn't this "ATD" etc?  Also, your HighValue variable is a variant, and should probably be a numeric (I'd actually consider using a LONG here rather than an INT).

I am assuming that an example of a SalesCategory would be "ATD" and therefore the highest value (and what DMAX would return) should be 700?

Here's a minor tweak to the code, this should work as you intended.  I'm also checking for invalid entries here (Nz), and converting the result to a Long Integer (CLng)

```
Dim lngHighestNumber As Long
Dim strHighCategory As String

strHighCategory = InputBox("Please enter data", "ENTER", "ENTER")

lngHighestNumber = Nz(CLng(DMAX("[SaleValue]", "SalesTable", "[SalesCategory] = '" & strHighCategory & "'")), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's right; it's supposed to return the highest value for the category designated. I changed HighCategory into a String and set the HighValue as a Long, but it's producing the same error. I feel like this might be a simple problem that I'm overcomplicating. I don't get why this isn't running. When I use the debugger it always breaks on the line with the DMax function, and I can't tell if it's something with the variables or a mixup with the access table.

Comment: Daft question, you have got the SalesValue field *in the table* set up as a numeric value as opposed to a string value, yes?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, it is a "Number" column in Access.

Comment: Your current answer seems a bit weird. `Nz(CLng())` should be `CLng(Nz())`, because `CLng()` throws a runtime error on `Null`. But I doubt that's the source of the answer (and you can find out by dimming them both as variants, that way you won't get type errors early on).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yeah I always get those the wrong way around when doing air-code.  My bad, good spot thank you.

Comment: @jahamj Ok then that's weird.  Is the name of the field you want the maximum of, [SaleValue] as opposed to [SalesValue]?  The code works as intended on a quick test DB I threw together.

Comment: @AdzzzUK Thanks again for your reply! I tried the code you provided and I keep getting the same error. I checked the spelling of all of the fields and they all seem to tie out to what is in the code. I think there might be some deeper issue outside of the code that I've mixed up somewhere. I might have to just try and remake the whole thing using the code that you provided for this section and see if there's something else that I may have screwed up in some other part of the database that is causing this. Thanks!